# How to delete the records entered to the MySql database during the tests run using Mocha and Chai

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have written a test program which can test number of endpoints written in node.js and check whether they 're working. I need a way to delete the records i entered to the database during the testing.

for example i need to delete the record added to the database after this test.

```
describe('/POST groups/AddGroupMember', () => {

before(function (done) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      done();
    }, 5000);
  });

let reqFields = {
                    "requestFields": {

                        "groupUID" : 50,
                        "custUID" : 20

                    }

                }

it('it should ADD the group member', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
    .post('/groups/AddGroupMember')
    .send(reqFields)
    .end((err, res) => {
        var uid = res.body.uID;
        console.log(uid);
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.be.a('object');


        done();
    });
});
```

});

Comment: It's better to run your tests in a different database and remove it when your tests are done. It is the safer way in case something happens when deleting the data from your actual database.

Comment: Thank you for your comment  .

Comment: @ThomasBormans Does `.end()` qualify as "remove it"?  Since I'm using MySQLPool, i'm currently closing it with `.end()`.

Comment: @JosephK. It's better to create a new question to prevent multiple discussions within one question.